# Unable to Install Client Side QC 10.0

Tags: hp-quality-center

Unable to Install Quality Center Client Side on the client's machine.

Operating System: Windows Vista
IE Version:9

We tried all the basic trouble shooting steps like deleting TD_80 folder from %temp% and performing a fresh installation.

Deleting Mercury Intercative folder from
C:\program files\common files

Running the internet explorer as Administrator.

None of the above solved the problem

we are recieving the below error message:::::

HP Quality Center: Unrecoverable Error Occured.

Reason: Could not load file or assembly 'interop.OTAClient, Version=10.0.02469,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=792843134cf0407a' or Contact your site administrator.

Details::::

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'interop.OTAClient, Version=10.0.0.2469, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=792843134cf0407a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'interop.OTAClient, Version=10.0.0.2469, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=792843134cf0407a'
at Mercury.TD.Client.Ota.Core.Application.SSPREnabled(String serverUrl)
at Mercury.TD.Client.UI.Core.Services.ConnectionManagementService.Initialize()
at Mercury.TD.Client.UI.Core.Services.BaseService.Initialize(IServiceManager serviceManager)
at Mercury.TD.Client.UI.Core.ServiceFactory`1.CreateService()
at Mercury.TD.Client.UI.Core.ServiceManager.ServiceCache`1.b__0()
at Mercury.TD.Client.UI.Core.ServiceManager.ServiceCache`1.CreateService(ServiceConstructorDelegate`1 serviceConstructor, T& service)
at Mercury.TD.Client.UI.Core.ServiceManager.ServiceCache`1.GetServiceEx(ServiceConstructorDelegate`1 serviceConstructor)
at Mercury.TD.Client.UI.Core.ServiceManager.ServiceCache`1.GetService()
at Mercury.TD.Client.UI.Core.ServiceManager.ServiceCache`1.GetBaseService()
at Mercury.TD.Client.UI.Core.ServiceManager.DoPublish[T](IServiceFactory`1 factory, Boolean activate)
at Mercury.TD.Client.UI.Core.ServiceManager.PublishAndActivate[T,C]()
at Mercury.TD.Client.UI.Core.ApplicationServicesPlugin.PublishServices(IServiceManager serviceManager)
at Mercury.TD.Client.UI.Core.Services.ApplicationService.InitializePlugins()
at Mercury.TD.Client.UI.Core.Services.ApplicationService.Start(Application application)
at Mercury.TD.Client.UI.Core.Application.Start()
at Mercury.TD.Client.UI.Core.Application.Initialize(String url, String configFilePath, IDictionary`2 properties)

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Answer (score 0):

Use the Quality Center Explorer Add-In rather than the one tied to the browser:

- [ALM Explorer 11](http://update.external.hp.com/qualitycenter/qc110/others/almexplorer/index.html)
- [QCExplorer 10](http://update.external.hp.com/qualitycenter/qc100/others/qcexplorer/index.html)
- [QCExplorer 9](http://updates.merc-int.com/qualitycenter/qc90/others/qcexplorer/index.html)
- [QC Forums](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Quality-Center-Support-and-News/Quality-Center-and-Windows-7/td-p/4630465)